# Mocking of new object and injecting it

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I want to write junit for below method

```
public class ManageProfile{

    public ResponseDTO create(SessionContext context, String flowId, Map<String, String> params) {
         ApiClient apiClient=new ApiClient();
         apiClient.setBasePath("ip");
         Service service=new Service();
         service.setApiClient(apiClient);
         ResponseDTO response= service.createProfile(new RequestDto()); 
         return response;
    }
}
```

Its not spring based application.

```
class Test

    @Test
    public void testCreate()   {
        
        SessionContext sessionContext = mock(SessionContext.class);
        ManageProfile manageProfile=new ManageProfile();
        Service service=mock(Service.class);
        
        when(service.createProfile(any())).thenReturn(new ResponseDTO());

        String flowId = "1";
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        ResponseDTO responseDTO=manageProfile.create(sessionContext,flowId,params);
        Assert.assertEquals("123"responseDTO.getId);
    }
}
```

I am not able to inject mock Service object in ManageProfile as it is getting created using new keyword

Comment: Please be specific. Are you using mockito or powermock? The later allows you to interfere with `new` , but honestly, that isn't advised. (but it is a solved problem, please do some research and read the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Use spy to mock some methods in ManageProfile class

```
public class ManageProfile{
public ResponseDTO create(SessionContext context, String flowId, Map<String, String> params) {
     ApiClient apiClient=new ApiClient();
     apiClient.setBasePath("ip");
     Service service = createService();
     ...
}
public Service createService(){
    return new Service();
}


class Test {
@Test
public void testCreate()   {      
    SessionContext sessionContext = mock(SessionContext.class);
    ManageProfile manageProfile= spy(new ManageProfile());
    Service service=mock(Service.class);
    when(mangaeProfile.createService()).thenReturn(service);
    ...
}
```